# Is it possible to add a new tab in the inspect element window of chrome?

Tags: javascript, web-inspector

I want to add a new tab in the inspect element window of chrome using javascript. Just like elements and console. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to build a devtool extension. Here's some docs from Google:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/integrating